# Drawing AWT BufferedImage on SWT Canvas

Tags: java, swt, awt

I am trying to write a SWT component, that is able to take and draw an instance of `java.awt.BufferedImage`. My problem is that SWT's `Image` and AWT's `BufferedImage` are incompatible: SWT components can't draw `java.awt.Image`, AWT/Swing components can't draw `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image`.

There are several approaches that try to solve this problem in other ways (which also may have some variations, but basically there are these two):

1. [Convert between SWT Image and AWT BufferedImage](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ConvertbetweenSWTImageandAWTBufferedImage.htm)
2. [Swing/SWT Integration](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html)

They all have shortcomings and didn't satisfy my expectations:

1. The first approach, to convert an SWT `Image`  to a `BufferedImage`, results in poor performance for large images due to the creation of a new `RGB` instance for every Pixel.
2. The second approach has several shortcomings in usability. See the "workarounds" at the end of the linked article.

This lead to the conclusion that I'd try my best to write a component (based on `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas` or `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite`) which allows to draw a `BufferedImage` directly without any conversion of images.

My approach was to draw it pixel by pixel. Therefore I simply had to get an instance of `GC`, walk the source `BufferedImage` line by line, left-to-right and drawing the corresponding `Color` using `GC.setForeground(Color color)` and `GC.drawPoint(int x, int y)`.

First, I created a new instance of `Color` for every pixel, which uses quite a lot of memory and adds an additional delay, since `new Color` acquires system resources and creating a new object for every pixel also takes its time.

Then I tried to pre-load all possible (24 bit) `Color`s into an array before drawing the image. This lead to an explosion of memory usage (>= 600 MB), which was clear before I was trying it, but I had to verify it.

Caching only the used Colors also lead to more memory consumption than would have been required.

I think there has to be a more low-level approach that doesn't require that much memory, since SWT is able to draw whole (SWT) `Image`s without consuming that much memory.

I would appreciate any ideas or solutions.

Comment: The method described in your first reference using RGB looks like it would be a lot faster - have you actually tried it?

Comment: I imagine that there is such an approach.  However, both AWT and SWT rely on native code to implement the low level graphics.  Therefore your low-level bridging would most likely involve some gnarly native code that operates on the native data structures used in the AWT and SWT cases.  And that would code would need to be implemented across multiple hardware and OS platforms.  Not pretty.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, but I wasn't satisfied with the `new RGB` calls for every pixel. It really is a lot faster than my own approach.

Comment: @StephenC Probably yes. But maybe somebody knows a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out there's a way to "convert" an `BufferedImage` to an `Image` by using the original image's data buffer if it is 24 bit RGB. This is possible, since the image formats are compatible.

```
final BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new File("some-image.jpg");

final PaletteData palette =
        new PaletteData(0x0000FF, 0x00FF00, 0xFF0000);

// the last argument contains the byte[] with the image data
final ImageData data = new ImageData(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(),
        24, palette, 4,
        ((DataBufferByte) original.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData());

final Image converted = new Image(getDevice(), data);
```

This way, one doesn't have to create thousands of new objects. This approach comes with the disadvantage that one needs to ensure that the original image is of type RGB 24 bit. Otherwise the image has to be converted to this format.

After that, an image can be drawn with the following code:

```
// get the GC of your component
gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Probably other bit depths can be converted in a similar way, but this is all I need for the moment.

Comment: Just curious, but why don't you simply load the image with SWT directly? Is there a reason to use the detour with Swing/AWT?

Comment: I get the image from another library I use and wanted to work around the hassle to save it do a temporary file and re-load it with SWT. That would take additional unnecessary seconds.

Comment: I adapted your code in this way to work with monochrome images:
    RGB[] colors = new RGB[]{new RGB(0,0,0), new RGB(255,255,255)};
  PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(colors);
  ImageData data = new ImageData(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(),
          1, palette, 4, ((DataBufferByte) original.getData(
            ).getDataBuffer()).getData());